# How to get the list of Organizations a user belongs to in GitHub?

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to do what the title says, using GitHub's API, I'm trying to get the list of orgs any user belongs to... my problem, is that I can't find a way to do it.

According to the API's doc: https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/ using this endpoint:

```
/users/:user/orgs
```

That should list them, but it's not doing it for my user, so I'm guessing this only lists orgs created by the user.

If this is the case, is there a way around it somehow, so I can get the list of organizations that any user belongs to?

Comment: Are you authenticating as the user whose organizations you want to fetch? If so, `GET /user/orgs` will return *all* organizations for that user (i.e., organizations where the membership is public *and* organizations where the membership is private). https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/#list-user-organizations

Comment: I am @jasonrudolph,but I get no orgs back... check my profile: github.com/deleteman You'll see there a few orgs, but if I log in and then check /user/orgs I get nothing (I'm using curl from php, to login and then I send the auth token when requesting /user/orgs)

Comment: Can you send the complete output of a `curl -v` request and response to https://github.com/support? We can take a closer look at your specific scenario and help you track down the issue. (Please be sure to mask any authentication credentials in your support request.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should but, as mentioned

- For my account, I don't belong to any organization: https://api.github.com/users/VonC/orgs
- `defunk`, however, is part of public orgs: https://api.github.com/users/defunkt/orgs

Since the [list orgs API](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/#list-user-organizations) will only list public memberships, regardless of authentication. (more precisely, [`GET /orgs/{org}/memberships/{username}`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/orgs#get-organization-membership-for-a-user))

> If you need to fetch all of the organization memberships (public and private) for the authenticated user, use the [List your organizations API](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/#list-your-organizations) instead.

Maybe your user is not part of any public orgs, only private ones.

---

More recently, using `gh`, the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli) after a [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login):

```bash
gh api \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  /user/orgs \
  --jq ".[].login"
```

One line:

```
gh api -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" /user/orgs --jq ".[].login"
```

Comment: What about my profile? I'm currently part of several organizations: github.com/deleteman but the API is returning an empty array, even if I'm authenticated.

Comment: @Deleteman Are those organizations public? And do you see your account in `https://api.github.com/orgs/<YourOrgName>/members`?

Comment: mh, apparently I'm not a public member on any of those organizations... that's why I'm not seeing then when I request the orgs for my user. Thanks!

Comment: The doc has been updated to include: `This method only lists public memberships, regardless of authentication.`.

Comment: @kytwb Thank you. I have updated the answer to reflect the current documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Use the route `/user/memberships/orgs`. For instance, using GitHub Cli:

```
$ gh api  /user/memberships/orgs  --jq '.[0].organization.login'
etsii2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to get the user's organizations that your authorization allows you to operate on in some way, you can use the [List organizations for the authenticated user](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/orgs/orgs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-organizations-for-the-authenticated-user) endpoint.

In cURL

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/user/orgs
```

where you need to substitute the `<YOUR-TOKEN>` by the `access_token` you get in the response after authentication.

In my case, using Postman

[image]

Answer (score -2):

just call /user/orgs to retrieve all organizations public or private

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @fkarakas.

Comment: It is very straight forward, no need to "detailed" explanation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33432332)